# InetNtop: can't find which header it is using

Tags: c++

Anyone knows what header I must include for the use of InetNtop function ?
I tried winsock2.h, ws2tcpip.h and i've include the Ws2_32 librabry. I am using windows 7
This is my error that i get an compile time: InetNtop : function could not be resolved

edit:
`char temp[10];

int bytes_recv = Recv(temp, sizeof(temp));

char result[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

InetNtop(AF_INET, (void*)(&temp[4]), result, sizeof(result));`

I am trying to print an IP what is in temp.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does your code compile?

Comment: it doesnt i get errors like  error: 'InetNtop' was not declared in this scope and that the name is not resolved

Comment: Look inside the header and see whether it is actually there, if it is not there, then no amount of project configuration can help you. Your best bet is to get an up-to-date copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `Ws2tcpip.h` is its actual header file.

EDIT:

According to the documentation, using this function *requires* your code to be compiled for Windows Vista or later. Since you *are* including the necessary header and yet the function is not visible, I surmise the you have not set the proper defines or compiler options to compile your code for a suitable version.

The actual Windows version that you are using is not important - what you are compiling for (i.e. the target version) is.

EDIT 2:

You should add the proper `#define` directive as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx) to indicate which Windows version you are compiling for. E.g.

```
#include <SdkDdkver.h>

#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA
#define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
```

Some of these defines overlap and may not be needed, but on the rare times that I code for Windows I just use them all to make sure :-)

EDIT 3:

Things are a bit different for MinGW/GCC:

```
#include <w32api.h>

#define WINVER                  WindowsVista
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS          WindowsVista
#define _WIN32_WINNT            WindowsVista
```

Note: These defines should be placed before including `Windows.h` or any other header but `w32api.h`.

EDIT 4:

From the `WS2tcpip.h` in Visual Studio 2010:

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)
.
.
.
PCSTR
WSAAPI
inet_ntop(
    __in                                INT             Family,
    __in                                PVOID           pAddr,
    __out_ecount(StringBufSize)         PSTR            pStringBuf,
    __in                                size_t          StringBufSize
    );

PCWSTR
WSAAPI
InetNtopW(
    __in                                INT             Family,
    __in                                PVOID           pAddr,
    __out_ecount(StringBufSize)         PWSTR           pStringBuf,
    __in                                size_t          StringBufSize
    );

#define InetPtonA       inet_pton
#define InetNtopA       inet_ntop

#ifdef UNICODE
#define InetPton        InetPtonW
#define InetNtop        InetNtopW
#else
#define InetPton        InetPtonA
#define InetNtop        InetNtopA
#endif
.
.
.
#endif  //  (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)
```

Therefore the critical define in this case is NTDDI_VERSION, as expected for a new API addition.

I cannot find the `InetNtop` definition in MinGW32/GCC-4.4.2, so it's quite possible that it is not supported in your version either.

Comment: Sorry,but how do i do that ? If you know.

Comment: I done this: #define _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA 0x0600
#define NTDDI_VISTA 0x06000000 with no effect

Comment: error: SdkDdkver.h: No such file or directory. I really HATE windows

Comment: @vBx: what is your compiler version?

Comment: You should really go with defining `#define WINVER` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT`. Your commend says that you defined `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`, which shouldn't bring you any benefit. Follow these steps: 1. include sdkdkver.h 2. define `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` to the value of `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` 3. include Ws2tcpip.h. Hope that helped.
Edit: Just saw your "error:": Against which SDK are you compiling?

Comment: It  gives me that the first and third are redefinision and, of course still can't find InetNtop :(

Comment: @vBx: I cannot find InetNtop in my MinGW include directory. It may simply not be supported using the GCC headers. Found it on VS 2010 just fine, though.

Comment: hey,thanks for the code...i have found another solution and it works,thank God ( http://memset.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/inet_ntop-for-win32/ ) :)

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% relevant, but for the linux/unix version of this call (`inet_ntop(...)`), you need to `#include <arpa/inet.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it exists in `Ws2tcpip.h`, the default target for most projects is Windows XP, and the function you are trying to use was introduced in Vista, so, you need to configure your project to target Vista instead. There are at least three things you can do here:

1. In your `stdafx.h` (if you have one), find the definitions of `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` [by default these are both `0x0501`], change them both to `0x0600`. Windows 7 is `0x0601`. Also, define `NTDDI_VERSION` to `0x06000000`.
2. If you don't have a `stdafx.h` header, add these definitions to your project's C/C++ preprocessor settings (`WINVER=0x0600,_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600,NTDDI_VERSION=0x06000000`).
3. As a last resort, define these manually before including any headers for that particular source file:

   ```
   #ifndef WINVER
   #define WINVER 0x0600
   #endif
   #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
   #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
   #endif
   #ifndef NTDDI_VERSION
   #define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000
   #endif
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
   ```

Also, make sure you have an up-to-date copy of `ws2tcpip.h`. For example, the copy that comes with Visual Studio 2005 does not have a declaration for `InetNtop`.

Comment: I added them to the preprocessor settings: g++ -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -O0 still it doesnt recognized the function

Answer (score 1):

Declare this function explicitly in your code.

```
const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t size)
{
  struct sockaddr_storage ss;
  unsigned long s = size;

  ZeroMemory(&ss, sizeof(ss));
  ss.ss_family = af;

  switch(af) {
    case AF_INET:
      ((struct sockaddr_in *)&ss)->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)src;
      break;
    case AF_INET6:
      ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ss)->sin6_addr = *(struct in6_addr *)src;
      break;
    default:
      return NULL;
  }
  /* cannot direclty use &size because of strict aliasing rules */
  return (WSAAddressToString((struct sockaddr *)&ss, sizeof(ss), NULL, dst, &s) == 0)?
          dst : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Ws2tcpip.h`, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).