# error using inet_ntop in Release mode but not in Debug Mode - using VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When building my app, I get "identifier not found" when building in Release mode for the inet_ntop function. However, no error occurs when building in Debug mode.  Any ideas how I can get it to compile in Release mode?

Comment: Try to link `Ws2_32.lib` library to your project and include `Ws2tcpip.h` header file where you use `inet_ntop` function. And I usualy use `InetNtop` function in Visual Studio projects (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['inet\_pton': identifier not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660203/inet-pton-identifier-not-found)

Comment: I already had Ws2_32.lib linked as an additional dependency and included Ws2tcpip.h in the header file.  I changed the code to use InetNtop and I'm still getting the error.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What is your windwos version? `InetNtop` is actually a macro. Are `InetNtopA` or `InetNtopW` functions available for your source file? Try include `Winsock2.h`. Is `Windows.h` header included? If you use `Windows.h`, try to rearrange inlucde order, change `Windows.h` with `Winsock2.h` or `Ws2tcpip.h`.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: May be this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890753/inetntop-cant-find-which-header-it-is-using

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I think that problem in project defines.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was a project defines issue.

Comment: Could you create an answer with steps how to solve this problem. I think it can be helpful for other users.

Comment: This is what I did: 1. Changed Windows.h with Winsock2.h or Ws2tcpip.h.
2. Went into Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor Definitions changed WINVER=0x06010000 since I’m running on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on Windows 10.
I just changed _WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 in  Project Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor Definitions.