# C undefined reference to InetPtonW

Tags: c, windows, reference, undefined

I'm trying to use `InetPtonW`:

```
if(InetPtonW(AF_INET, argv[1], &ThisSenderInfo.sin_addr)<=0) { 
    return 1; 
}
```

However I get the following message when compiling:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'InetPtonW' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
undefined reference to `InetPtonW'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read the documentation located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inetptonw#requirements) and I've followed everything but still can't get it to work.

• I'm compiling with Ws2_32 library `gcc test.c -o test -lws2_32` using MinGW

• I've included the needed header files `#include <ws2tcpip.h>` and `#include <windows.h>`

• I've tried using `InetPton` but it returns the same error

• Running on Windows 10

Comment: This API is available starting with Windows Vista. Make sure you are targeting Windows Vista or a later version. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers) for instructions.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4890753/694576, if not a duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1):

I recall running into this exact issue some many months ago. @alk's comment points to a question whose [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4890776/3821300) feels *very similar* to what fixed it for me.

You should be able to `#define` a version macro (or two) before your `#include` lines to fix it.

While I feel strongly that [the aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4890776/3821300) is correct, I'll update this answer later today when I can verify.

## Update!

The code I was referencing above doesn't have `InetPtonW` in it anymore but it had the necessary `#define`s in it. Here's a brief example that compiles on my machine (win10/mingw64/gcc 8.2.0):

`Z:\Some\Directory>gcc test.c -o test -lmswsock -lws2_32`

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA
#define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is "test.c", please pardon the lack of error checking. */

int main(void) {
    BYTE ipbuf[4] = {0};

    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);

    printf("%d: ", InetPtonW(AF_INET, L"127.0.0.1", &ipbuf));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%hhu.", ipbuf[i]);

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Output should look like:

```
Z:\Some\Directory>gcc test.c -o test -lmswsock -lws2_32

Z:\Some\Directory>test
1: 127.0.0.1.
Z:\Some\Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a linking error. which say that, included library path, the given function not found. please make sure your dll library path for InetPtonW or make sure that is available in your system or not.