# inet_ntop() was not decleared in this scope

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I am building a TCP server using C: I included the library where the inet_ntop() function is (WS2tcpip.h), yet my compiler returns with the following error:

> **'inet_ntop' was not declared in this scope**

I have no idea why; even my IDE doesn't notice anything wrong (I use vscode as my IDE because it can detect errors in real-time without compiling every time) yet when I compile it gcc returns the error I stated previously.

What I have included and defined:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

The faulty line of code:

```
if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXHOST, 0) == 0) {
        printf("\n[CONNECTION]: %c connesso sulla porta %c", host, service);
    } else {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        printf("\n[CONNECTION]: %c connesso sulla porta %c", host, ntohs(client.sin_port));
    }
```

Any helpful tip is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InetNtop: can't find which header it is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890753/inetntop-cant-find-which-header-it-is-using)

Comment: Defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is supposed to exclude certain API like the Socket API.

Comment: in most situations, the function: `inet_ntop()` is prototyped in the header file: `arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim,  That `#define` must be BEFORE the header files are included.  That `#define` after the header files are included has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue.
`inet_ntop()` seems to be declared depending on the windows version, _WIN32_WINNT .

Solution was to define this preprocessor value, before including windows/socket headers:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#elif _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600
    #undef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Windows? If not, try including arpa/inet.h

Comment: Only Windows has ws2tcpip.h

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VSCode? or manual compilers?

I have pretty same error with my code.
Im using C++ in my code but I get error with these: 
'getnameinfo' was not declared in this scope
'inet_ntop' was not declared in this scope

I use VS Code. What I realize is, when I copy paste same code to VS, it works! I think its something with compiler problem.

Still can't compile my code in VSCode but in VS it works.

Comment: I suggest you to rephrase a little your answer so that the actual answer ("It works with VS code") becomes prevalent. Currently the prevalent part in your answer contains other questions..

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is most likely **outdated** and contains an outdated version of the `<ws2tcpip.h>` header which does not contain the `inet_ntop` function implementation.

I've had the same issue and resolved it by downloading `MinGW-w64 9.0.0 with GCC 11.1.1` from [here](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases).

Comment: There are also many other reasons like outdated OS version, or any problem related to OS