C++ 'inet_pton' Function cannot be used on Windows
These are my header files (on Windows):

When I compile the program, this error will be on the display:

'inet_pton' was not declared in the scope

I try to update my mingw but it's useless.

By the way, 'inet_ntoa' has the same error.
Can you tell me what I can do to solve this problem? I'm a college student and just studying TCP which can be used on a Windows system.
I tried updating the MinGW, gcc but useless;
ps:StackOverflow had a similar issue on it that caused my issue to be closed, but that issue was posted ten years ago, and I've tried all the comments below, and it clearly didn't fix the issue.So I updated the question yesterday and I just want to find a solve method~Thanks a lot.
This is the only problem for my program.

#pragma comment(lib, "...") does nothing when compiling with MinGW as far as I know. Those definitions are inside a #if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA) block. You might try defining _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0600 or higher. Usually if you don't define it the header has a default for Windows 10 in the Windows 10 SDK but MinGW might define it lower automatically.

ok, thanks, and I tried to add the #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00 follow the headfile.But it  was still not working...The Wrong-Message is same. (was not declared)

Compile:
1.warning: "_WIN32_WINNT" redefined (0x0A00)
2.note: this is the location of the previous definition (0x502)
3.'InetPton' was not declared in this scope
OMG~...

If the define would work it needs to be before any headers are included or added to the compile command line. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75965248/920069

Ok~it's Solved~Thank you for your patience.
